router.replace resets Tanstack Table's paginations page index to it's initial value
I'm using next.js 14 and Tanstack Table to list my data and I wanted to store filters and pagination as search parameters. I managed to store filters but when it comes to pagination there is this issue.
const [pagination, setPagination] = React.useState(() => {
  const pageIndex = searchParams.get("pageIndex");
  const pageSize = searchParams.get("pageSize");

  if (pageIndex && pageSize) {
    return {
        pageIndex : +pageIndex,
        pageSize : +pageSize,
    };
  } else {
    return {
      pageIndex : 0,
      pageSize : 13,
    };
  }
});

onPaginationChange: (i: any) => {
  const tempObject = await i(pagination);

  const oldParams = Object.fromEntries(searchParams.entries());
  const oldParamsUrl = new URLSearchParams(oldParams);

  oldParamsUrl.set("pageIndex", tempObject.pageIndex);
  oldParamsUrl.set("pageSize", tempObject.pageSize);
  router.replace("?" + oldParamsUrl.toString());

  setPagination(tempObject);
}

I can story pageSize in the url but when I try to store pageIndex it immediately changes to the initial state. I'm open to any ideas. Thank you.
I'm expecting it not to reset to it's initial state.

If you are using searchParams, you don't have to use state to track pageIndex and pageSize since you will get that both from the searchParams. Also it is quite a pain currently to update searchParams in next app router so i recommend using a library like nuqs which simplifies the process. Also updating search params like you are doing will cause server request which will re-render your server components as well and you don't seem to want that for your case. nuqs library gives you an option for that as well.

Thank you for your response @Dorji. I'm going to try nuqs. The reason that I'm using a state is to pass it as a param to the Tanstack Table's state option. But the solution you proposed makes much more sense. Have a great day.
